# Python multiprocess sharing of a huge numpy bool array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean, python-multiprocessing

I am having a problem sharing a numpy array. The idea is this, I have a large numpy bool array (600000x6000 = 3.6GB) I would like to make shared and pass to multiple threads, using mp.Pool, as input for sklearn's MLPRegressor with varying ANN shapes. However, I cannot figure out how to make a bool mp.Array.

The code I've got going is a bit convoluted, but here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
import ctypes

def train((NN,data)):
 #train NN using sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor
 #will return the accuracy of the regression (r)
 return (NN,r)

#leaving out the target data and NN_shape generation for simplicity
np_data = np.array([[False]*6000]*600000,dtype='bool')
shared_arr = mp.Array(ctypes.c_bool,np_data.shape[0]*np_data.shape[1])
arr = np.frombuffer(shared_arr.get_obj())
arr = arr.reshape(np_data.shape)
training_runs = [(x,arr) for x in NN_shapes]

p = mp.Pool()
results = p.map(train, training_runs)
```

This gives me the error message at the reshape step:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 450000000 into shape (600000,6000)
```

I have seen the examples of doing this using doubles (dtype='double' and ctypes.c_double). However, this costs 8x the memory (28.8GB), and causes a memory error at the mp.Array step when I run out of RAM.

```
mmap.error: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
```

Any help is much appreciated!